# Interpretation of R output for mixed ANOVA model

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, interpretation, split-plot

I had to do a mixed ANOVA. How can I interpret the results?

- `Power` (high power / low power) is the within factor.
- `interaction` (first / second) is the between factor.
- `agent` is the subject.
- The dependent variable is `Dominance`.

This is the output:

```
Error: agent
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
interaction:Power  1   2.51   2.514   1.454  0.233
Residuals         57  98.55   1.729               

Error: agent:Power
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
interaction  1   0.85    0.85    0.64    0.427    
Power        1  46.63   46.63   35.20 1.85e-07 ***
Residuals   57  75.52    1.32                     

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Mainly I do not know what the term "`Error`" means, and how I can interpret the rest according to this term.